# How to get the number of elements in an unbuffered channel

Tags: go, deadlock, channel, goroutine

I am in a situation where my program is deadlocking and I want to debug this and tell how many elements are in an unbuffered channel, is there any way to do this in Go?  The following code does not output a 2 as I would expect (further it deadlocks, which is also something I cannot find a reason for)

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    channel := make(chan string)
    done_channel := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        channel <- "value"
        channel <- "value"
        fmt.Println(len(channel))
        done_channel <- true
    }()
    variable := <- channel
    fmt.Println(variable)
    ok := <- done_channel
    fmt.Println(ok)
}
```

Comment: an unbuffered channel doesn't contain any elements, it's unbuffered.

Comment: @JimB I am in a situation where I am blocking infinitely on a channel,  I want to debug this to see if there is anything at all in the channel because from stepping through code, it does appear that elements have been sent to the channel, how would you recommend i do this?

Comment: @JimB But when you take values out of a channel, you can get the exact number of values that were put in before blocking forever, so there must be some values stored internally right?

Comment: An unbuffered channel is synchronous, you can only send when there is a receiver. The channel doesn't store (buffer) anything. You're blocking because you're trying to send 2 values, but only receiving 1.

Comment: @JimB Ah ok I think I understand, is there a way to create a channel with a dynamically sized buffer?  So the channel becomes somewhat like a threadsafe queue?

Comment: No, you have to define the size of the channel buffer when you create it.

Comment: You cannot dynamically alter the size of an existing channel, but you can dynamically create new channels in such a way as to present an effectively unbounded queue. In other words, you be unbounded horizontally instead of vertically.

Comment: @JoelCornett Essentially you mean a linked list of channels? But then that would also have to be synchronized, for example when adding a new horizontal partition to the channel right?  What is the Go way of going about doing this?  should I just look into the "sync" package?

Comment: here ya go. I must warn you though, this may have a bug in it. https://play.golang.org/p/hSDCeJ90D-

Comment: This one is slightly better, but I think we are getting off topic from your original question, no? https://play.golang.org/p/eQ_JgHbKtL

Comment: @JoelCornett: that is a bad idea. Not only have you added a race condition on the slice of channels, prevented the ability to select on multiple channels concurrently, and lost the ability to stop the range by closing the channel, but your receive loop defaults into a busy loop which uses 100% CPU and eventually will block the scheduler.

Comment: @JimB I'm not arguing with you about any of those. Out of curiosity though, what's the problem with having a race condition on the slice?

Comment: @JoelCornett: it's a data race. Best case your program crashes, but anything could happen, including retruning invalid results or other memory corruption.

Comment: @JimB maybe I'm making some invalid assumptions, but channels are reference types, as are slices. The worst case I see is that the append generates a new backing array and copies the channel references into it, causing that iteration of the ouput goroutine to potentially 'miss' some buffer channels. Effectively, there are only reads happening in the race cases (unless the assignment to ub.buffer is nonatomic).

Comment: @JoelCornett, there are no benign data races, and any Go program that contains data races has undefined behavior. Always check your programs with the race detector. Also see https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/01/06/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong

Comment: @JimB I was working under the assumption that assignments to struct fields (and variable assignments in general are atomic). Are you telling me that that is incorrect?

Comment: @JoelCornett: your assumptions are incorrect, the only atomic operations are through the sync/atomic package. This isn't the place for this conversation -- Start by carefully reading the go memory model document, and the article I linked.

Comment: @JimB point taken. Also, interesting reading.

Answer (score 3):

Go runtime has a deadlock detector that you just came across. The detector is giving you all information you need to solve the problem. You don't need to analyze the channel length.

Let's look at the output of your program

```
value
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!

goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
main.main()
    /home/grzesiek/test.go:16 +0x17e

goroutine 5 [chan send]:
main.main.func1(0xc42001a0c0, 0xc42001a120)
    /home/grzesiek/test.go:10 +0x99
created by main.main
    /home/grzesiek/test.go:13 +0x9c
exit status 2
```

It is saying that all goroutines are asleep (blocked) and no progress is possible. The blocked goroutines are listed altogether with the blocking operation and line that caused the blockage.

Goroutine 1 (main) is trying to read from channel `done_channel` in line 16.

Goroutine 5 (created in line 13 by the function call operator `()`) is trying to write to channel `channel` in line 10. It will never go further as there is no goroutine on the other side of the chanel. Therefore it will never write to `done_channel`.

The program is blocked because no goroutine can go further and main goroutine is also blocked.

Please be aware that the Go program ends when main goroutine ends, so this dead lock would not occur if you would not try to read from `done_channel`.