# Writing twice to an unbuffered channel lead to different results depending on the select usage. Why?

Tags: go, channel

Consider two examples:

First one:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        c := make(chan int)
        go func(){
                c <- 1
        }()
        go func(){
                c <- 2
        }()
        select {
        case <-c:
                fmt.Println("<-c:", <-c)
                fmt.Println("<-c:", <-c)
        }
}
```

As far as I know, what should happen is: Two goroutines spawn and write to the same channel, one of them blocks and waits for the main goroutine to read.

But I don't understand what happens with the second goroutine. Does it block because the channel is unbuffered, and it **can't** hold two values by **design**.

With this piece I am getting a deadlock. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41860130/how-to-get-the-number-of-elements-in-an-unbuffered-channel).

And if so, how this code is running then?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        c := make(chan int)
        go func(){
                c <- 1
        }()
        go func(){
                c <- 2
        }()
        select {
        case forget := <-c:
                fmt.Println("forget:", forget)
                fmt.Println("<-c:", <-c)
        }
}
```

Comment: The first program deadlocks because the main program executes three receive operations `<-`, but only two values are sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It looks like using `case <-c` actually reads from the channel and does not simply check it for having a value as I thought.